# Header scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have such a code and I want a class to be added to my header during scrolling, but nothing works after the function `jQuery(window).scroll(function() {`

this is my html

```
<header class="site-header">
   
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <nav class="nav-header"></nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

it's my jQuery

```
jQuery(function() {
var header = jQuery(".site-header");
console.log("work");
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {    
    console.log("not work");

    var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 500) {
        header.removeClass('site-header').addClass("FireBrickRed ");
        header.addClass("transition");
    } else {
        header.removeClass("FireBrickRed ").addClass('GreyHeader');
        header.addClass("transition");
    }
});
});
```

The class is not being added ... In the browser, even after scroll, the console log function is not outputting anything

**Solutions**

I removed the window and added a body and it worked.

Comment: Thank you for providing code, but can you explain the problem you're facing and trying to solve?

Comment: The class is not being added ... In the browser, even after scroll, the console log function is not outputting anything

Comment: Is `window` the actual container you're scrolling?

Comment: @ChloeAnderson I just want that when I am at the very top of the page, the header does not have a class, and when I start scrolling from the top of the page, then the class is added

Comment: @ChloeAnderson I removed the window and added a body and it worked. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some content so you can scroll :)

```js
jQuery(function() {
var header = jQuery(".site-header");
console.log("work");
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {    
    console.log("not work");

    var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 500) {
        header.removeClass('site-header').addClass("FireBrickRed ");
        header.addClass("transition");
    } else {
        header.removeClass("FireBrickRed ").addClass('GreyHeader');
        header.addClass("transition");
    }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="site-header">
   
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <nav class="nav-header">
        header
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<main>
  <p>More content</p>
  <p>More content</p>
  <p>More content</p>
  <p>More content</p>
  <p>More content</p>
  <p>More content</p>
  <p>More content</p>
  <p>More content</p>
  <p>More content</p>
  <p>More content</p>
  <p>More content</p>
  <p>More content</p>
  <p>More content</p>
  <p>More content</p>
  <p>More content</p>
  <p>More content</p>
</main>
```

`